# Is there a way to check if an npm package needs a publish and only do a publish then?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I am creating a single code base containing multiple projects and each project can be published.

To create a streamlined continuous integration process I want my build agent to run a single command that publishes all the projects that need to be published. Obviously this doesnt work because a publish fails if it would publish over a previously published version and that causes the command to fail and all following commands do not execute. Something like this:

```
"build-package1": "ng build package1",
"publish-package1": "npm publish ./dist/package1",
"build-package2": "ng build package2",
"publish-package2": "npm publish ./dist/package2",
"build-all": "npm run build-package1 && npm run build-package2",
"publish-all": "npm run publish-package1 && npm run publish-package2"
```

So in this scenario if I run build-all, and then publish-all and package1 has not got a version change in it's package.json file then the command will fail and package2 will not be published.

Is there a command I can do that checks if a publish is needed before trying to publish?

I have seen this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line/539293#539293

Ideally though I think finding out if a publish would work before attempting it might be cleaner.

Comment: As far as I know you && will wait for a valid exit code before moving to the next operation, a single & will run all commands (and will not wait for the end) - this is however only a cosmetic change as you'll still be creating the errors by publishing over the existing version

Comment: This might help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/publish-if-not-published. Check out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to install npm locally to the project and then use imperative npm commands to check the latest published version, and the node file system to check local versions before using an imperative npm publish command

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as npm from 'npm';

function getLocalPackageData(path): Promise<IPackageData> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path + '/package.json', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

      const pData = JSON.parse(data as unknown as string);
      resolve({ version: pData.version, name: pData.name });
    });
  });
}

function getPublishedPackageData(packageName: string) {
    npm.commands.show([packageName], function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);

      const latestVersion = Object.keys(result)[0];
      resolve({ version: latestVersion, name: result[latestVersion].name });
    });
}

function needsPublish(latestPackageSegments: IPackageVersionSegments, localPackageSegments: IPackageVersionSegments): boolean {
  const majorGreater = localPackageSegments.major > latestPackageSegments.major;
  const majorEqual = localPackageSegments.major === latestPackageSegments.major;
  const minorGreater = localPackageSegments.minor > latestPackageSegments.minor;
  const minorEqual = localPackageSegments.minor === latestPackageSegments.minor;
  const bugFixGreater = localPackageSegments.bug > latestPackageSegments.bug;

  return majorGreater ||
    (majorEqual && (minorGreater || bugFixGreater)) ||
    (majorEqual && minorEqual && bugFixGreater);
}
```

from there you can achieve checking local against published and do:

```
npm.commands.publish(projectPathsToUpdate, (error, res) => {

    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    console.log('================= published: =================');
    packagesToUpdate.forEach(p => console.log(p.name + ' updated to ' + p.version));
  });
```

hope this helps someone in the future - possibly me again.

Comment: It is no longer possible to import `npm` as of v8: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.0.0